# Strokes with same width change when exporting to .psd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, stroke, raster

I draw some shapes and paths with the pen tool in Adobe Illustrator. I put a stroke on all of them with the same width. For some reason I must export my work as .psd but when I export it and change it to pixels the strokes haven't the same width: one of them is one pixel the other is two pixels. I don't know how to solve this problem? Or why is this happening.

Comment: Why are you converting the strokes to a raster image?  PDFs can handle vectors just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator, go to **menu View** > **Pixel Preview**

If the shapes or strokes don't match the pixel grid, when they get rasterized the thickness will vary in at least one pixel.

**Stroke width with pixel preview:**
[image: stroke width pixel preview]